# Getting coordinates on touch event relative to scrollable map

Tags: android, scroll, coordinates

Is there a way to get the coordinates of a touch event on a scrollable map?

Meaning when I touch at one point on the screen, `getX()` and `getY()` return the respective values and then when I scroll the map, the coordinates returned should be relative to the map, not the screen.
eg. I have a 750x750 background map, and my device screen size is 480x800.
when I first touch, say the coordinates returned are (100, 200). now when I scroll the map and touch somewhere else,  I get the coordinates as 200, 200.
I want to get the coordinates with respect to the map and not the screen.

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time and have scoured the net and other sites in vain.

please help.
thanks in advance
\m/

i need the coordinates coz i'm developing a game in which  i have a large map and objects placed on it. when i scroll the map, i need the objects to move along with in the same position.
here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         touchStart.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
     x = ev.getX();
     y = ev.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        newX = ev.getX() - touchStart.x + prevPicStart.x;
        newY = ev.getY() - touchStart.y + prevPicStart.y;
        if ((newX <= 0 && newX > 0 - mBG.getWidth() + Craz.DISP_WIDTH)) {
            picStart.x = newX;
          }
        if ((newY <= 0 && newY > 0 - mBG.getHeight() + Craz.DISP_HEIGHT)) {
            picStart.y = newY;

        }
        invalidate();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        prevPicStart.x = picStart.x;
        prevPicStart.y = picStart.y;

        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBG, picStart.x, picStart.y, paint);

    canvas.translate(picStart.x, picStart.y);

    mBDoor.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: is it a custom view? did you implement scrolling with `scrollTo()`/`scrollBy()`? you could just add `getScroll*()` values to your screen-relative coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty easy. When you scroll your map, you have an offset. If you scroll to the right (the background will move to the left), your offset will be negative. Lets say, you have an offset on x of -50, and you click the screen coordinates 100 you simply do the math:

```
mapCoordX = screenX - offsetX; // makes: 100 - (-50) = 150
```

just looking at the X coordinate, for Y it should be the same.

I have written a [tutorial about a map of tiles and scrolling over it](http://www.droidnova.com/create-a-scrollable-map-with-cells-part-ii,678.html). Maybe you take a look at it, too.

Pseudocode!

```
for (int id = 0; id < mapSize; id++) {
  Tile tile = new Tile(id);
  startX = id * tileWidth;
  startY = id % rowLenght + id / rowLenght;
  tile.setBackground(createCroppedBitmap(background, startX, startY));
}
```

Comment: @WarrenFaith can you tell me how to tile a large image? my background map is 750x700

Comment: i need the coordinates coz i'm developing a game in which i have a large map and objects placed on it. when i scroll the map, i need the objects to move along with in the same position. i've posted my code up.

Comment: @Blacklight when you follow the posted tutorial, you should be able to create a tiled map. You can use the creation of the tile objects to crop the area of the background. I edited my answer for a minimal introduction

Comment: @WarrenFaith  
thank you for your help. i got it to work properly.
i need to make a path in this i.e my character sprite has to follow a certain path to move from one point to another. how do i do this in a tiled map?

Comment: For path traveling/finding, check this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: @WarrenFaith  hey i need some help in the Pseudocode u posted. i'm not able to get it to work. please can u tell me exactly how to create a cropped bitmap? thing is i have a large image that i want to tile.

Comment: There are two ways: tile it with an external program or crop it on the fly with `createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)` you can also draw the full image and create a virtual tiled map on top. So you can move both and you don't need to handle a bitmap for every tile... there a lot of possible solutions. If you stuck again, create a new question...